# How to remove columns having null or blank values on all rows in Datatable

Tags: c#, linq

I want to remove A-1 Note,B-1 Note and Mezz columns having null values from Datatable in C#

[image]

Comment: How do you mean "remove"? do any of your records have those values? Are you looking to remove the fields from the database, from the view? what happens if some have some values?

Answer (score 0):

```
var startcolumnindex=21;
      //  RemoveEmptyColumns
            for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= startcolumnindex; i--)
            {
                DataColumn col = dt.Columns[i];
                if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(r => r.IsNull(col) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r[col].ToString())))
                    dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            //  RemoveEmptyColumns
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code sample will help you to remove all Columns having all blank or null values in particular column.

```
for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (dt.AsEnumerable().All(r => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(r[colMaping.Key]))))
        dt.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
}
```